# Extracting the first word from every value in a list

Tags: python, string, list, split

So I have a long list of column headers. All are strings, some are several words long. I've yet to find a way to write a function that extracts the first word from each value in the list and returns a list of just those singular words.

For example, this is what my list looks like:

```
['Customer ID', 'Email','Topwater -https:', 'Plastics - some uml']
```

And I want it to look like:

```
['Customer', 'Email', 'Topwater', 'Plastics']
```

I currently have this:

```
def first_word(cur_list):
    my_list = []
    for word in cur_list:
        my_list.append(word.split(' ')[:1])
```

and it returns `None` when I run it on a list.

Comment: add `return my_list` at the end of the function, or use a list comprehension `[phrase.split(' ')[0] for phrase in l]`

Comment: How is this related to pandas? Also consider that your function doesn’t actually have a return statement. That explains why it returns None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> l = ['Customer ID', 'Email','Topwater -https://karls.azureedge.net/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/627x470/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/g/fgh55t502_web.jpg', 'Plastics - https://www.bass.co.za/1473-thickbox_default/berkley-powerbait-10-power-worm-black-blue-fleck.jpg']
>>> list(next(zip(*map(str.split, l))))
['Customer', 'Email', 'Topwater', 'Plastics']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension to return a list of the first index after splitting the strings by spaces.

```
my_list = [x.split()[0] for x in your_list]
```

Comment: So does this look correct? Sorry - I'm new to python and struggling a bit. Thank you for your help!

I'm still getting `None` as the output.

  `def first_word(list):
         my_list = []
         my_list = [word.split()[0] for word in list]`

Comment: don't create a function for it, just create your list, save it to the variable 'your_list' and then do what the solution of @dfundako says. What is happening in your function has to do with local vs global variables and I don't think you're ready for it lol

Comment: Your answer is not the main reason why his program returned None (main problem with the original code). But I have credited your work. Can you explain how your notation works?

Answer (score 1):

**To address "and it returns None when I run it on a list."**

You didn't return `my_list`. Because it created a new list, didn't change the original list `cur_list`, the `my_list` is not returned.

**To extract the first word from every value in a list**

From @dfundako, you can simplify it to

- `my_list = [x.split()[0] for x in cur_list]`

The final code would be

```
def first_word(cur_list):
    my_list = [x.split()[0] for x in cur_list]
    return my_list
```

Here is a demo. Please note that some punctuation may be left behind especially if it is right after the last letter of the name:

- `names = ["OMG FOO BAR", "A B C", "Python Strings", "Plastics: some uml"]`
- `first_word(names)` would be `['OMG', 'A', 'Python', 'Plastics:']`

Answer (score 0):

`[column.split(' ')[0] for column in my_list]` should do the trick.

and if you want it in a function:

```
def first_word(my_list):
    return [column.split(' ')[0] for column in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=\d\d\d)\d*` try using this in a loop to extract the words using regex